# What does it mean when I compile and run the program and it says "JUnit Version

Tags: junit, compilation

What does it mean when I compile and run the program and it says "JUnit Version...

```
JUnit version 4.8.2

Time: 0.002

OK (0 tests)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JUnit is a Framework, that you can use to test your application. If you don't have any test-classes created the UnitTest won't do anything. But if you write test-classes the IDE will check if the program works correctly. See also: https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/JUnit

Comment: How do I fix it such that it show the output instead of the JUnit Version thing?

Comment: What do you mean? Please be more specific.